# How create table use j2html?

Tags: java, j2html

I get acquainted with j2html and I try a make table, but have some problems:

```
  main().with(
                    table(

                            tr(
                                    td().with(
                                            img().withSrc(imagePath+photo)

                                    )

                                    td().with(
                                            span(name)
                                    ),
                                    td().with(
                                            span(String.valueOf(quantity))
                                    )
```

after img().withSrc(imagePath+photo) I see mistake, but I don't understand what want from me Idea
May be you can show how create table with image+name+ some quontity + colspan for several cells

Comment: Seems to me you want a comma after the `)` on the line after the `img().withSrc` line. If this is Java code. (Or JavaScript. Or any of several related languages.)

Comment: I try comma, it's not working. This framework allow in java the create web application

Answer (score 3):

(pre v.1.0.0): The tag-methods don't accept DomContent children, so you need to do `table().with(`, `td().with(` etc, not just `table(` and `td(`:

```
String htmlTable = table().with(
    tr().with(
        td().with(
            img().withSrc("path" + "photo")
        ),
        td().with(
            span("name")
        ),
        td().with(
            span(String.valueOf("quantity"))
        )
    )
).render();
```