# Dynamic table creation using J2HTML in java

Tags: j2html

How to create dynamic table using j2html and java, I have map so when I iterate it if there is any content I need to create table and new rows according to the content . How can achieve this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create table use j2html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794735/how-create-table-use-j2html)

Comment: @AlexShesterov, I got the solutions anyways thank you so much